# An Optimized algorithm for finding all Sundays and Fridays for a given interval

Tags: c#, algorithm, linq, datetime

I have a flag enum for representing every day of the week. (Sunday, Monday etc.). Lets call this the `WeekDay` enum. Now given a interval find all dates for the days in the `WeekDays`variable.

For eg: `WeekDays daysAll = WeekDays.Sunday | WeekDays.Friday;`
Now find the dates for all the Sunday and Friday dates in a given interval.

So i thought of the following logic: Find the first Sunday, Friday, as in the above example.
Add these dates to a temporary dictionary. Now iterate that dictionary and keep on adding 7 days till the end interval is reached.

```
int dayCounter = 0;
WeekDays daysAll = WeekDays.Sunday | WeekDays.Friday;
Dictionary<DayOfWeek, DateTime> tempDict = new Dictionary<DayOfWeek, DateTime>();
for (var day = intervalStartDate.Date; (dayCounter < 7 && day.Date <= intervalEndDate.Date); day = day.AddDays(1))
{
     WeekDays check = GetWeekDayFromDayOfWeek(day.DayOfWeek);  //This Function converts from the DateTime DayOfweek enum to the WeekDays enum.
     if ((check & daysAll) == check)
     {
         tempDict.Add(day.DayOfWeek, day);
     }
     dayCounter++;
}
```

Now keep adding 7 days for every date in the dict till end interval is reached:

```
if (tempDict.Keys.Count > 0)
{
    List<DateTime> allDates = new List<DateTime>();
    var keys = new List<DayOfWeek>(tempDict.Keys);
    bool opComplete = false;
    while (!opComplete)
    {
        foreach (DayOfWeek dayOfWeek in keys)
        {
            if (tempDict[dayOfWeek] > intervalEndDate.Date) { opComplete = true; break; }                        
            allDates.Add(tempDict[dayOfWeek]);
            tempDict[dayOfWeek] = tempDict[dayOfWeek].AddDays(7);
        }
    }
}
```

So my question is: Can this algorithm be improved? Can LinQ be used to make the intent more clearer in the code itself?

Answer (score 4):

Performance optimization and clearer code are not the same in most cases.

The clearer LINQ version would be like this:

```
public IEnumerable<DateTime> IntervalDays(DateTime start, DateTime end)
{
    if (start > end)
        yield break;

    var d = start.Date;

    while (d <= end.Date)
    {
        yield return d;
        d = d.AddDays(1);
    }
}
```

and the you write the query as in this example:

```
IntervalDays(startDate, endDate)
             .Where(d=>d.DayOfWeek==DayOfWeek.Friday || d.DayOfWeek==DayOfWeek.Sunday);
```

The good thing here is you can easily query other days of the week etc.

For the optimized code, if you mean performance, you'd better not iterate one by one but find the first Friday or Sunday and move along by adding 2 or 5 days depending on the date

Comment: The LINQ looks cleaner, but as for optimization, in the question itself the first Sunday & Friday is found and then 7 is added. Do you think this algo can be written with LINQ as well?

Comment: @Abhi: Although your algorithm for adding 7 days *might be* faster, you have the algorithm setup time to consider, and there is non-zero time involved in setting up the iterator for every week to go over your dictionary of keys. Your algorithm would likely be *slower* if you were looking for four or more days. This answer gives you a simple working method that does what you want. You should use it to get your program working. If profiling shows that this method is causing a bottleneck in your working program, then you should think about optimizing it.

Answer (score 0):

Few ways, as a general method, pass in the day of week you want with start and end dates.

```
private List<DateTime> GetDates(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate, DayOfWeek dayOfWeek)
{
    var returnDates = new List<DateTime>();
    for (DateTime dateCounter = startDate; dateCounter < endDate; dateCounter = dateCounter.AddDays(1))
    {
        if (dateCounter.DayOfWeek == dayOfWeek)
        {
            returnDates.Add(dateCounter);
        }
    }

    return returnDates;
}
```

Or return full date range and query that using linq.

```
private List<DateTime> GetDates(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
{
    var returnDates = new List<DateTime>();
    for (DateTime dateCounter = startDate; dateCounter < endDate; dateCounter = dateCounter.AddDays(1))
    {
        returnDates.Add(dateCounter);
    }

    return returnDates;
}
```

query:

```
var myDates = GetDates(DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddDays(30)).Where(i => i.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Friday);
```

Comment: Here we are iterating all dates, not so good for performance, in our code example we have found the first Sunday, Friday and then added 7 hence. Can that be done with LINQ as well?

Comment: if you really care that much about performance I would advise against Linq.

Comment: The algorithm is of prime interest, the implementation is also important but comes after the algo for me. As for performance of LINQ vs for's, there are many many arguments, but i would go by LINQ because in future frameworks performance might get even better, also would make me look cooler :)